# resource for understanding the kernel and drivers

Tags: linux, drivers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux Kernel: Good beginners' tutorial](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1003/linux-kernel-good-beginners-tutorial)

What **resources** are available if I wanted to *develop*, *change* and *understand* **device drivers**.