# Learning the Unix/Linux Kernel

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel

I've been reading [The Design of the UNIX OS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132017997) by Maurice J Bach. It's good overall.

However, I learn better with audio/visual aids so does anyone know some good video lecture series or tutorials for either Unix or the Linux kernel?

I would also like to walk through the kernel code after I've learnt the basics of the kernel. So any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Probably of interest: [Understanding the Linux kernel source](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/797/22651)

Comment: Also: [Linux kernel: Good beginners' tutorial](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1003/22651)

Comment: @ire_and_curses I've looked at these links but they most contain references to textbooks or written tutorials.

Comment: There are several videos on youtube, e.g.: [Linux Kernel](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAo1QCQXODo&feature=related) [Linux Kernel Module Programming](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-O6GsrmOUgY&feature=relmfu) [Greg Kroah Hartman on the Linux Kernel](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2SED6sewRw)